# Parsing string to enum from JSON in Golang

Tags: json, go, enums, unmarshalling

I have an enum defined as

```
type MyEnum int

const(
   FirstEnum MyEnum = iota
)
```

Then, I have a json that has the key-value pair `"Key": "FirstEnum"`. I'm unmarshalling like this.

```
var data map[string]interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(json), &data)
x := data["key"].(MyEnum)
```

When I run this, however, I get the error:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not ps.Protocol [recovered]
        panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not ps.Protocol
```

Is there a way to get this to work like a normal conversion of a string representation of a enum to enum type in Go?

Comment: First, this won't work with `interface{}` at all, since the unmarshaler will then unmarshal it to the default type of string. So you'll need a struct. Then you'll need to write a custom `UnmarshalJSON` function to handle things for you.

Comment: That's sounds like a lot of work... How does go handle unmarshalling json to custom types? Always need to write a custom unmarshaller?

Comment: Just read the documentation.  Declare a struct, make a pointer to a struct instance and then use that directly in ``Unmarshal``

Comment: You don't _always_ need to write a custom unmarshaler. Only when you want custom behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out something that works in a similar way (at least works for my current situation):

Use `string` for `enum`-like constants:

```
type MyEnum string

const(
   FirstEnum MyEnum = "FirstEnum"
)
```

Now, use the decoding json to custom types as mentioned [here](https://gobyexample.com/json).

```
data := MyJsonStruct{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(json), &data)
```

`MyJsonStruct` would look something like:

```
type MyJsonStruct struct {
    Key MyEnum
}
```

You can then make MyJsonStruct implement the `Unmarshaler` interface, so you can validate the given values.

```
func (s *MyJsonStruct) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Define a secondary type so that we don't end up with a recursive call to json.Unmarshal
    type Aux MyJsonStruct;
    var a *Aux = (*Aux)(s);
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &a)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Validate the valid enum values
    switch s.Key {
    case FirstEnum, SecondEnum:
        return nil
    default:
        s.Key = ""
        return errors.New("invalid value for Key")
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5uy88z6ddn9)

Comment: If you're willing to use a string type in Go, this is the easiest approach indeed.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to raise any errors if the string does not match one of the enum values.